# How to filter documents in $match by the last 36 months in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, datetime, aggregation-framework

I want to only obtain documents where this specific field "EffectiveDate" is greater than 36 months ago.  I have tried:

```
"$match" : 
{"member.MemberEnrollmentSpans.MemberEnrollmentSpan.EffectiveDate": {$gte: 
ObjectID.createFromTime(Date.now() - 36*31*24*60*60)}}
```

But It doesn't seem to like the '`ObjectID.createFromTime`' statement, it say my error is at the 'O' position, `"Unexpected Character 'O'"`

Does `$match` operator not recognize this or is my syntax wrong ?

```
var date = new Date();
(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 36));
var dateInput = date.toLocaleDateString();


db.getCollection("Members").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "member.MemberInfo.BusinessUnitCode" : "20"
             }
        }, 
        { 
            "$match": { $expr: { $lt: [{ $toDate: dateInput }, 
"$member.MemberEnrollmentSpans.MemberEnrollmentSpan.EndDate"] } } 
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : {
                "path" : 
"$member.MemberEnrollmentSpans.MemberEnrollmentSpan", 
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : false
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : {
            "EffDate" : "$member.MemberEnrollmentSpans.MemberEnrollmentSpan.EffectiveDate", 
            "PlanProduct" : "$member.MemberEnrollmentSpans.MemberEnrollmentSpan.PlanProduct", 
            "PlanProductCode" : "$member.MemberEnrollmentSpans.MemberEnrollmentSpan.PlanProductCode", 
            "BenefitPackage" : "$member.MemberEnrollmentSpans.MemberEnrollmentSpan.BenefitPackage", 
            "EndDate" : "$member.MemberEnrollmentSpans.MemberEnrollmentSpan.EndDate"
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$_id", 
            "items" : {
                "$addToSet" : {
                    "EffDate" : "$EffDate", 
                    "PlanProductCode" : "$PlanProductCode", 
                    "PlanProduct" : "$PlanProduct", 
                    "BenefitPackage" : "$BenefitPackage", 
                    "EndDate" : "$EndDate"
                }
            }
        }
    }
], 
{ 
    "allowDiskUse" : true
}
```

);

Comment: How does your `EffectiveDate` look like ?

Comment: @srinvasy `ISODate("2015-08-01T00:00:00.000+0000")`

Comment: `var date = new Date();
(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 36));
var dateInput = date.toLocaleDateString();
console.log(dateInput)` --> Can you execute this in console of chrome, I did try & everything is working fine, if not can you change the variable names of `date` & `dateInput` & try ? Also is this aggregation & these few line of code wrapped in any function ?

Comment: @srinivasy I dont know why Its not working.  I will use pymongo for this problem for now.  could you help me with this most pressing question of mine its much more important [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59688316/pivot-embedded-documents-keys-to-its-own-document-column-in-table-view-mongo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

**In your code :**

```
let date = new Date();
(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 36));
let dateInput = date.toLocaleDateString(); // 1/10/2017
```

**Query 1 :**

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([{ $match: { $expr: { $lt: [{ $toDate: dateInput }, "$date"] } } }])
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e17a6a5627ef7823644a088"),
    "date" : ISODate("2015-08-01T00:00:00.000Z")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e17a6ac627ef7823644a13f"),
    "date" : ISODate("2016-08-01T00:00:00.000Z")
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e17a6c0627ef7823644a2d6"),
    "date" : ISODate("2019-12-01T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e17a6c0627ef7823644a2d6"),
    "date" : ISODate("2019-12-01T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

(Or) as from here [getOlderRecordsByMins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59672662/query-documents-that-are-older-than-x-minutes-in-mongoose), you can do this, both would get you same results but getting `36` months to this number `94608103680` is a bit hard, both of these queries are simple & fast enough with less operators being used - but if you think getting `94608103680` through code is easier then this go ahead with this :

**Query 2 :**

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([
    { $match: { date: { $gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 94608103680) } } }])
```

Comment: This gives me the Error:  `[js] SyntaxError: redeclaration of let date :`

Comment: @BenSmith :  It might be javascript code issue, apart from here `let date = new Date();`, Did you ever declare `date` anywhere up above ?

Comment: No I didnt.  I posted it just as you wrote at the very beginning of the script

Comment: @BenSmith : Are you sure, can you search in your code for `date` & check if it's duplicated, Or can you post your code with issue..

Comment: Yes I am sure. I have now declared any other variables called "date".

Comment: @BenSmith : Where are you executing this code ? Can you give me exact code & aggregation query that your'e using..

Comment: I cant post it here becuase its too long and my work blocks the chat feature for security reasons

Comment: maybe you can raise another question or edit this question with the issue !!

Answer (score 1):

I take the approach that 36 months is 3 years. So, the aggregate queries can be one of these:

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $match: { 
          EffectiveDate: { $gt: new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 3 ) ) } 
      } 
  }
] )

db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $match: { 
          $expr: {
              $gt: [
                  "$EffectiveDate",
                 { $dateFromParts: { 
                        year : { $subtract: [ { $year: ISODate() }, 3 ] } , 
                        month : { $month: ISODate() }, 
                        day: { $dayOfMonth: ISODate() }  
                 } }
              ]
          }
      } 
  }
] )
```

With the following input documents:

```
{ "EffectiveDate" : ISODate("2016-12-10T03:42:26.751Z") }
{ "EffectiveDate" : ISODate("2020-01-05T03:42:26.751Z") }
{ "EffectiveDate" : ISODate("2017-08-10T03:42:26.751Z") }
{ "EffectiveDate" : ISODate("2017-01-09T03:42:26.751Z") }
{ "EffectiveDate" : ISODate("2018-05-30T03:42:26.751Z") }
```

these will be returned:

```
{ "EffectiveDate" : ISODate("2020-01-05T03:42:26.751Z") }
{ "EffectiveDate" : ISODate("2017-08-10T03:42:26.751Z") }
{ "EffectiveDate" : ISODate("2018-05-30T03:42:26.751Z") }
```

Comment: Awesome.  Why do you need to declare `new Date()` three times though?

Comment: That is not needed if you do the calculation in the shell; it is only because it was within the aggregation.