# Query documents that are older than X minutes in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am looking for a way to query documents that were created before X minutes in **mongoose**.

Here is my schema.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 6,
        maxlength: 18,
        match: /^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[_-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/,
        unique : true,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
    },
}, {timestamps:true})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
query = {
    timestamp: { 
        $lt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * X)
    }
}
```

Comment: nice (+1), For mins it's good enough but Only thing concerned me is when you want to use it for months, let's say if we need it for 3 months - Simply doing this `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 90` will not work as this in `ms != months` :: `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 90 != 3 months`, So Conversion might become a bit hard if doing for n' months, just in that case you may try this :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59672412/how-to-filter-documents-in-match-by-the-last-36-months-in-mongodb-aggregation/59673182#59673182